# HTML5 alternative for rel=""

Tags: html, href, rel

What is the HTML5 alternative for `rel=""` in the following code:

`<span class="gte" rel="gte">`

Without the `rel=""` attribute, the page is not functional, nor will it validate as HTML5 compliant.

Comment: You need to elaborate on what isn't functional.

Answer (score 4):

[The `rel` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#attr-link-rel) is perfectly valid in HTML5, so it doesn't need an alternative, however it needs to be on a `a`, `link` or `area` element, because it defines the *rel*ationship between the current document and the linked document.  Having it on an element which is not a type of link doesn't make any sense.

In order for your markup to validate you need to change the `span` to `a` or `link` and the value you use with the `rel` attribute needs to be allowed by the [link types listed in the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#linkTypes) or have been [approved by the microformats development process](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values).  I don't see `gte` listed in either place, maybe you could explain what you expect it to mean?

You say 'the page is not functional' but do not describe what functionality you're expecting?  Normally a `rel` attribute does nothing, it's just semantic information.  If you're just trying to add additional information to this element for use in by a script or other tool related to your own site then you should instead use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes).

If this information isn't helpful to you, perhaps you can explain more clearly what your problem is?